# Recommend a good quality blimp and dual-mount system for pair of Oktava 012s?

Tags: microphone, blimps, field-recording, recommendations

Have used the [Shure A27M](http://www.fullcompass.com/product/305049.html) mounting kit and really liked it, but also need a couple of blimps with shockmounts that will accommodate pencil mics like the O12s, Neumann 184s, etc. A pistol grip attachment would be a huge +1. Thanks in advance -

Oh, and did I mention affordable??   :)

Comment: wow! this has been up here for a while. we really need some of those other manufacturers to start cranking out some stereo mount pistols. rycote's got the market cornered on those.

Answer (score 2):

In relation to the Rode Blimp. Here's a great article detailing how you can fit a stereo ORTF/NOS hybrid into one:

http://audiofieldrecordings.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/rode-nt5-microphones-modified-ortfnos-recording-technique/

This is presuming you want a spaced xy pair, rather than MS?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

I know someone who mounted schoeps on a stereo rycote hot shoe bar http://www.rycote.com/products/accessoriesspares/stereo_bar_assembly/ the smaller one and used the rycote ball gags for wind protection and it worked quite well.  he was doing ORTF In the field.  You might want to give Buzz Turner a call at http://turneraudio.com.  he's been the guy who distributes rycote in the US and is super knowledgeable.  He's helped me work through a number of funky setups over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Most affordable blimp is the RODE blimp.  Probably best in its price range.

$300
[RODE BLIMP](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/579335-REG/Rode_BLIMP_Blimp_Complete_Windshield.html)

Comment: i think he's looking for something to mount two pencil mics within one system. rode doesn't have an m/s style mount yet for their blimps.